# Remove unnecessary information from SNP rsid names

Tags: regex, bioinformatics, genetics

I have a dataset of SNPs, which aren't coded the way I need them. Instead of being coded just `"rsNUMBER"` they also have the information of the chip-analyses. For example: `GSA-rsNUMBER` or `psy-rsNUMBER`

Some also have the information of the chip-analyses at the end `rsNUMBER_CNV_SULT1A3` .

Is there a way to remove the chip-information? My data is in plink binary format `.bed`, `.bim`, and `.fam`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Perl to get a simple hack working:

```
echo -e "1 rs123-bob 0 123456 N N\n1 bob-rs123 0 123456 N N\n" | perl -p -e "s/(\S+\s+)\S*(rs[0-9]+)\S*(.*)/\1\2\3/g;
```

Above assumes `.bim` format.